# Database Connection Pool in Symfony 2 Web Application

Tags: symfony, doctrine, database-connection

I am using Symfony 2 and doctrine. Is there a way to specify database connection pool size
parameters.ini  entries are:

```
database_driver   = pdo_mysql
database_host     = localhost
database_port     = 3306
database_name     = *****
database_user     = root
database_password = *****
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify 'pooled' parameter to use a pooled server with the oci8 driver (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html).

So, I think the answer on your question is 'not quite'.